# Redis Cache Query using multiple criteria

Tags: java, caching, redis, spring-data-redis

I have price data from ecommerce like follwoing. Each row is considered as an Domain object lets say PriceInfo

```
+-----------+----------+-------+------------------+
| ProductId | Provider | Price |       Time       |
+-----------+----------+-------+------------------+
| iphone    | Amazon   |   200 | 13-12-2021 12:50 |
| iphone    | Ebay     |   201 | 13-12-2021 12:50 |
| iphone    | Alibaba  |   202 | 13-12-2021 12:50 |
| GalaxyX2  | Ebay     |   195 | 13-12-2021 12:50 |
| GalaxyX2  | Alibaba  |   196 | 13-12-2021 12:50 |
+-----------+----------+-------+------------------+
```

Clients are interested in getting all prices from a particular vendor or prices for a single product from various vendors

1.Get price from Ebay

```
+-----------+----------+-------+------------------+
| ProductId | Provider | Price |       Time       |
+-----------+----------+-------+------------------+
| iphone    | Ebay     |   201 | 13-12-2021 12:50 |
| GalaxyX2  | Ebay     |   195 | 13-12-2021 12:50 |
+-----------+----------+-------+------------------+
```

2.Get price for iphone

```
+-----------+----------+-------+------------------+
| ProductId | Provider | Price |       Time       |
+-----------+----------+-------+------------------+
| iphone    | Amazon   |   200 | 13-12-2021 12:50 |
| iphone    | Ebay     |   201 | 13-12-2021 12:50 |
| iphone    | Alibaba  |   202 | 13-12-2021 12:50 |
+-----------+----------+-------+------------------+
```

How can I define my Redis cache key and how to query the DB to get the above 2 results ?

While saving the pojo I am doing following using Jedis library in java spring boot project:

```
    public void save(PricingInfo pricingInfo ) {
        template.opsForHash().put(HASH_KEY, pricingInfo.getProductId(), pricingInfo );
    }
```

Comment: Did you check the Redis Module https://redisearch.io ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `RedisReposiroty` to get these data, in Redis repository you can define a collection as

```
@RedisHash("productPrice")
public class ProductPrice implements Serializable {
    @Id private String id; // assign id as productId#provider
    @Indexed
    private String productId;
    @Indexed
    private String provider;
    private Double price;
    private Long timestamp;
}
```

We've added two indexes in this, one for productId and another one for provider.

Define a Redis repository with two methods as

```
@Repository
public interface ProductPriceRepository extends CrudRepository<ProductPrice, String>  {
    List<ProductPrice> findByProductId(String productId);
    List<ProductPrice> findByProvider(String provider);
}
```

Now you can `autowired`  ProductPriceRepository in the service.

To save a record you need to call `repository.save` method.

Comment: Thanks you very much for this. It worked!

Comment: How to expire particular entry after certain time ? I can see we can set expiry at template level but expires entire hash. I want expiry at each entry of hash.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62331270/how-can-we-configure-ttl-for-redishash-using-springboot